# aiohttp test with several servers

Tags: python-3.x, aiohttp

Trying to do a test that communicates with several instances of a web-server (which also communicates between them). But the second one seems to override the first however I try. Any suggestions of how to solve this.

So far I have this:

```
import os
from aiohttp.test_utils import TestClient, TestServer, loop_context
import pytest
from http import HTTPStatus as hs

from mycode import main

@pytest.fixture
def cli(loop):
    app = main(["-t", "--location", "global", "-g"])
    srv = TestServer(app, port=40080)
    client = TestClient(srv, loop=loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(client.start_server())
    return client

@pytest.fixture
def cli_edge(loop):
    app = main(["-t", "--location", "edge", "-j", "http://127.0.0.1:40080"])
    srv = TestServer(app, port=40081)
    client = TestClient(srv, loop=loop)
    loop.run_until_complete(client.start_server())
    return client

async def test_edge_namespace(cli, cli_edge):
    resp = await cli.put('/do/something', json={})
    assert resp.status in [hs.OK, hs.CREATED, hs.NO_CONTENT]
    resp = await cli_edge.get('/do/something')
    assert resp.status in [hs.OK, hs.CREATED, hs.NO_CONTENT]
```

The above call to `cli.put` goes to the server intended for `cli_edge`. I will have several more tests that should communicate with the servers.

Using Python 3.7 and pytest with asyncio and aiohttp extensions.

Comment: It actually works, I had used globals in my server implementation, which obviously would not work when running two servers in same process. After fixing that it worked. Also the internal inter-communication between the servers worked on the `-j` url specified.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested code works, the error was elsewhere in the server implementation.

You can add:

```
def fin():
    loop.run_until_complete(srv.close())
    loop.run_until_complete(client.close())
request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

and the `request` param in the pytest fixtures to close connections nicely.